# Latex : New listings : lstnewenvironment

Tags: latex

I want to define a new listings.

```
\begin{script}{caption:Algorithm caption}{label:alg-label}
    aaa
\end{script}
```

I define  like this :

```
\newcounter{script}
\lstnewenvironment{script}[2]{
    \renewcommand\lstlistingname{Script}
    \setcounter{lstlisting}{\value{script}}
    \lstset{}
} {\addtocounter{script}{1}}
```

Like this I have no error, but I don't have the caption. Maybe I need to add something in the \lstset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\lstset{
    caption= #1, 
    label= #2}
}
```